# How to manually update Nmap's Ncat on Centos 7

Tags: centos, netcat, nmap

How do I manually upgrade the `nmap-ncat` package on Centos 7?

Answer (score 2):

Check version:

```
$ nc --version
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
```

Remove Yum package and replace with RPM package.

```
$ sudo yum remove nmap-ncat
$ wget https://nmap.org/dist/ncat-7.60-1.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -i ncat-7.60-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Symlink `nc`

```
$ which ncat
/usr/bin/ncat
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ncat /usr/bin/nc
```

Check version post-install:

```
$ nc --version
Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```